# listing files from directory by passing command line arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to list files from any number of directories by using command line arguments.
I am trying to pass the directory paths through the command line and display files that are in searched directories. Something like this. 
"Directory: PATH1"
files
files
files

"Directory: PATH2"
files
files

etc.

So I am using $* to pass all of the command line arguments but it only displays files from the first listed directory.

```
#!/bin/bash


cd $*
for filename in *
do
        echo "Directory: $*"
        echo $filename
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this should work:

```
dirs=$*
for dir in $dirs
do
  echo "Directory: $dir"
  for filename in $(ls $dir)
  do
        echo $filename
  done
done
```

Comment: first I have tried just copying your script, but it gives me Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "done")

Comment: Avoid $* when you mean "$@".

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you have a space in a directory name you might want to use "$@", and it doesn't hurt to check that a directory exists:

```
  for dir in "$@" ; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
      echo "Directory: $dir"
      ls "$dir"  # If all you want is to show the contents, this should do
    else
      echo "Not a directory: $dir"
    fi
  done
```